# HTACCESS Remove Extension and change Query Results

Tags: .htaccess

Alright, i'm trying to clean up my url's... but failiing miserably: I want to have a url that looks like `mysite.com/front_door/some_url_here`. But I keep getting a 500 error. Below is my .HTACCESS, i'm sure its something i've done wrong as this is only my third or fourth time working with HTACCESS.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*[^/]) $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=(([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+))$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/page/%1.php [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what's causing your 500 server error:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*[^/]) $1.php [L]
```

Since your regex doesn't match the beginning or end of a request, it can literally match *anything*. That means if you go to

```
http://mysite.com/index.php?pid=1234
```

And then get redirected to

```
http://localhost/page/1234.php?pid=1234
```

The request `/page/1234.php` matches the first rule, via the regex: `(.*[^/])`, and gets rewritten to `/page/1234.php.php`. Then the rewrite engine loops, and the same thing happens again, first rule matches and then rewrites to: `/page/1234.php.php.php` and keeps going until you get the 500 error.

Not sure what it is you're trying to do with that rule, but a guess is that you want to be able to request `/file` and get served `/file.php`. Your rule needs to be like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1.php [L]
```

Also, your query string will continue to be at the end of your second rule's redirect, because you need a `?` at the end of the target:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/page/%1.php? [R=302,L]
```

Without that `?`, the query string just automatically gets appended to the end.